# How can I enable HTTPS on XAMPP?

Tags: php, https, xampp

I am trying to run a project via HTTPS on XAMPP.
I have tried to configure SSL in xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf as this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/yourProject
    ServerName yourProject.whatever
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```